# Code Igniter - Put a URL into URL parameter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

In Code Igniter, I am using the built-in URL class

I have a problem here. I want to include a referrer URL into current URL.

Example, localhost/from_referrer/`/account/verify/email/b4a98ddd44`

The `/account/verify/email/b4a98ddd44` is the URL that I want to include into current URL.

I have tried urlencode(). It looks like this

```
/account/login/from/%2Faccount%2Fverify%2Femail%2Fb4a98ddd44
```

but it doesn't work. CI assumes I want to go to

```
/account/login/from//account/verify/email/b4a98ddd44
```

but i want to go to

/account/login/from/`/account/verify/email/b4a98ddd44`  (highlighted one is just parameter)

anyone of you have any idea how to make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your url always start with the same segments you can try to get all segments in an array and strip the segments at the beginning you do not need.

```
$segs = $this->uri->segment_array();
unset ($segs[0]); //unset /account
unset ($segs[1]); //unset /login
unset ($segs[2]); //unset /from

$uri = implode('/', $segs);
echo $uri; // echoes "account/verify/email/b4a98ddd44"
```

another **possible** solution:
This is not an awnser to your question but maybe a (beter) work around.

why not use http referer in combination with codeigniter flash data? 
when a user goes to the login page, set the flash data in the *controller*

```
$this->session->set_flashdata("referer",$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

then after the user logged in, you can use this to retrieve the value again

```
$uri = $this->session->flashdata("referer");
```

[flash data codeigniters manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: i think a better way would be using flash data :P

Answer (score 0):

Here is the just an idea

try replacing `/` with `-` for your referrer url like

```
$referrer= str_replace('/', '-', '/account/verify/email/b4a98ddd44');
```

so your url will become something like this

```
account/login/from/-account-verify-email-b4a98ddd44
```

Now in your `account controller's` login function get this like

```
function login(){
$referrer= str_replace('-','/',$this->uri->segment(4));
}
```

Now you can do this in many ways like you can just hash the url and append in your url but if you append `/account/verify/email/b4a98ddd44` in url CI will treat it as the individual params like

```
account => is the uri segment(4);
verify=> is the uri segment(5);
email=> is the uri segment(6);
b4a98ddd44=> is the uri segment(7);
```

So you need to make a string without the `/` so it will come in one uri segment

Hope it makes sense